# How do you get the aspect fit size of a uiimage in a uimageview?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

When print(uiimage.size) is called it only gives the width and the height of the original image before it was scaled up or down. Is there anyway to get the dimensions of the aspect fitted image?

Comment: What units are you looking for? Points?  How are you planning to use this information?

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough context. I’m using the uiimagepicker controller to pick an image and I need the width of the image so I can move the image to the right, but it only gives the width of the original image (in pixels). CGRect is in points so I would convert it to points but I doesn’t really matter to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is a function in `AVFoundation` that can calculate this for you:

```
import AVFoundation

let fitRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: imageView.bounds)
```

now `fitRect.size` is the size inside the imageView bounds by maintaining the original aspect ratio.

Comment: Nice.  I verified that this is giving the same results as my calculations.

Comment: @vacawama Thanks. Although this is what I would use, I really think that an answer like yours is useful for understanding the logic behind it.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to calculate the resulting image size in `Point`s yourself*.

> * It turns out you don't.  See [Alladinian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541834/1630618).  I'm going to
> leave this answer here to explain what the library function is doing.

Here's the math:

```
let imageAspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
let viewAspectRatio = imageView.frame.width / imageView.frame.height

var fitWidth:  CGFloat   // scaled width in points
var fitHeight: CGFloat   // scaled height in points
var offsetX:   CGFloat   // horizontal gap between image and frame
var offsetY:   CGFloat   // vertical gap between image and frame

if imageAspectRatio <= viewAspectRatio {
    // Image is narrower than view so with aspectFit, it will touch
    // the top and bottom of the view, but not the sides
    fitHeight = imageView.frame.height
    fitWidth = fitHeight * imageAspectRatio
    offsetY = 0
    offsetX = (imageView.frame.width - fitWidth) / 2
} else {
    // Image is wider than view so with aspectFit, it will touch
    // the sides of the view but not the top and bottom
    fitWidth = imageView.frame.width
    fitHeight = fitWidth / imageAspectRatio
    offsetX = 0
    offsetY = (imageView.frame.height - fitHeight) / 2
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

It helps to draw the pictures. Draw a rectangle that represents the
imageView. Then draw a rectangle that is narrow but extends from the
top of the image view to the bottom. That is the first case. Then draw
one where the image is short but extends to the two side of the image
view. That is the second case. At that point, we know one of the
dimensions. The other is just that value multiplied or divided by the
image's aspect ratio because we know that the `.aspectFit` keeps the
image's original aspect ratio.

A note about `frame` vs. `bounds`.  The `frame` is in the coordinate system of the view's superview.  The `bounds` are in the coordinate system of the view itself.  I chose to use the frame in this example, because the OP was interested in how far to move the imageView in it's superview's coordinates.  For a standard imageView that has not been rotated or scaled further, the width and height of the frame will match the width and height of the bounds.  Things get interesting though when a rotation is applied to an imageView.  The frame expands to show the whole imageView, but the bounds remain the same.

Comment: I’ve you have any extra time do you mind explaining this to me. Because I’ve been trying to solve this for the last week and I was able to get the width but not the height. Anyways thank you!